# Check if a specific row exists, and if it doesn't, add a new one

Tags: c#, sql

I'm beginner in SQL and C#. My question is: how do I check whether a row in the table exists or not? Here is my code that I am currently using:

```
var conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source");
conn.Open();            
var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO  Results (PlayerName) VALUES (@PlayerName)  " , conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PlayerName",_playerName);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

I want to check if the player name exists or not, and if not, then add it to the table.

Comment: Before `INSERT` execute another query to `SELECT` and get the count. Later use `cmd.ExecuteScalar` to check the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check it with `Select` statement first and then `insert` it if it is not exist.

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and commands automatically instead of calling `Close` method manually.

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString))
using(var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "Select Count(*) From Results Where PlayerName = @playerName";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@playerName", _playerName);
    con.Open();
    int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    if(count == 0)
    {
        // It means it does not exist.
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Results(PlayerName) VALUES (@playerName)";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: this introduces a race condition, the record could be inserted inbetween the two command executions, you can do it in with 1 query (my answer below) which is also better for performance as its only 1 round trip.

Answer (score 2):

```
if not exists(select null from Results where PlayerName=@PlayerName) begin INSERT INTO  Results (PlayerName) VALUES (@PlayerName)  end
```

Comment: I prefer this method because you only need to dispatch one command to the database